# Getting location values to populate in text box javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the GPS coordinates to populate in the text box on this sandbox: https://jsfiddle.net/8pkmrsj7/

```
function geoFindMe() {
    var output = document.getElementById("out");

    if (!navigator.geolocation){
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
    }

    function success(position) {
        var loc  = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;
        output.innerHTML =  loc ;
    };

    function error() {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
    };

    output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
};
```

```html
    <p>
        <button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button>
    </p>
    <div id="out"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="out" />
```

I'm close, but am just missing something.  Any pointers?

Comment: There's no question here? Also, your fiddle works fine for me. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Note that on desktops, unless you have a GPS device connected you are not likely to get high accuracy coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 elements with same ID, so make the input as `out_input`:

```
<body>
  <p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
  <div id="out"></div>
  <input type = "text" id = "out_input"/>
</body>
```

To set the input value update to textbox:

```
  function success(position) {
    var loc  = position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("out_input").value =  loc ;
  };
```